# Making shell_exec work the way sh does

Tags: php, apache2, shell-exec

I have apache2, php5 installed.
I'm trying to execute the next code in my php script

```
chdir('/var/www/');
shell_exec('/usr/bin/omxplayer -o hdmi "'.$file_name.'" < omfifo &');
shell_exec('echo -n . > omfifo');
```

`$file_name` is a file and it does exist in /var/www directory.
www-data user is in sudoers file. /var/www/ is 0777.
generally shell_exec does work I checked it with this code

```
<?php
shell_exec('sh boo.sh');
?>
```

boo.sh

```
echo "Download finished" | wall;
```

When I execute the code with `omxplayer` in just a console it works fine.

Comment: You should make sure your environment (like PATH) is set. You can execute the commends in a single call to `shell_exec`. Also, when you run the first command it might just get an EOF from `omfifo` causing omxplayer to exit.

Comment: Why does `www-data` being in the `sudoers` file matter? (Also: not necessarily a good idea).

Comment: This is my `$PATH` variable -/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
It doesn't get EOF while executing in shell. Why can it be so?
Putting www-data shouldn't really matter. Server is in my local network only

Comment: Besides, I can launch omxplayer without using pipes.

Comment: I mostly meant the PATH (and other enviroment variables) in the shell your shell_exec is executed. In your second example running `sh` explicitly  might load some settings making a different environment. You can use output redirection for *stderr* to get any possible error messages with `omxplayer 2> errorlog.txt`